# Qt Creator qml: Use (extra) Qt Components library (ubuntu)

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick-designer

When I create a new Qtquick qml project and modify a qml file in "Design" mode I see a limited number of Qt Quick Basic components under the window Library QML Types
(like `Rectangle` and `Button`)

When navigate to the folder `/opt/QTSDK/QtCreator/lib/qtcreator/qtcomponents/`
I see a lot more components like `CheckBox` or `RadioButton`

How I can use these / see these in Design mode?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a year old, but I was looking for an answer to this just today.

To use a [Button](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-button.html), CheckBox, RadioButton and other convenient controls, you have to

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
```

at the top of your QML file.

[[Qt Quick Documentation]](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-index.html)